# Extracting a list while testing a condition on extracted entries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries `fruitLoads`, all dictionaries with the same keys. I want to extract a list containing all entries with a certain name which satisfy a certain condition.

```
apples = [i['Apples'] for i in fruitLoads if i['Apples'] != 0]
```

1. Is there a way to avoid repeating `i['Apples']`?
2. Would this solution be applicable if in both entries I had `float(i['Apples'])` instead?

Comment: Just as a side note, the time complexity of accessing an item from a `dict` is on average `O(1)` (worst case `O(N)` although rare), so I wouldn't be too concerned about it.

Comment: @Cyber rare is an understatement.

Comment: @Cyber for me the problem it's more about avoiding typical cut&paste errors when later on I'll have to take 'Pears', 'Oranges' and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a nested generator expression:

```
apples = [v for v in (i['Apples'] for i in fruitLoads) if v != 0]
```

although it could be made a little more readable by assigning the generator to a separate variable instead:

```
apple_loads = (i['Apples'] for i in fruitLoads)
apples = [v for v in apple_loads if v != 0]
```

Now you can incorporate the conversion as well:

```
apple_loads = (float(i['Apples']) for i in fruitLoads)
apples = [v for v in apple_loads if v != 0]
```

Comment: Very interesting, I thought the intermediate assignment would assign a newly created list, and not the generator itself. So I understand that, if after the assignment fruitLoads changes, also apple_loads "changes" (but not apples, which is indeed a list), the different kind of parenthesis matter a lot!

Comment: @Antonio: they do; generator expressions are evaluated only when iterated over. Execution is postponed until the `for v in apple_loads` loop iterates. As such you create a pipeline.